# Where to see detailed error logs while using react native expo cli?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been using react native cli to build react native apps where I could see error logs in the terminal from which I ran `react-native start` command now I have used an expo project but I could'nt see any deatiled error log with expo cli.
This is the error Im getting while running the app but I'm not able to findout where this error is located as I couldnt see any deatiled error log with expo

[image]]

this is the only log I'm able to see
[image]

I cant figure out where the error is located at.Where can I see detailed error log? since I'm getting this error on app start up I cant put it into debug mode as well

Answer (score 0):

Usually they appear in the console where "expo start" is run from. Sometimes I find they only occur on my device, though, too. I can't exactly explain it myself.

However, in this specific case, the answer appears in the image you posted so you shouldn't need to hunt much.

It suggests you need to find out where WebView is being used from an old/deprecated location and re-link it to use the packaged version of it as prescribed in the message.

So run "expo install react-native-webview" to get it, and then fix your imports to import from that package space accordingly.

If you're not using it explicitly, check 3rd party libraries that may be old and still using it. They may have upgrades that move past the deprecated use case.